# How to go to a new frame by clicking on a button in java?

Tags: java

I am new to java and implementing GUIs and i m stuck ... i have to make on frame containing username and password and when i click on submit i am directed to another frame known as menu in which i have four buttons now i want to click on a button and redirect to another frame but i am unable to do this .... please help me!!!

here's my code:

```
  import javax.swing.*;
  import java.awt.*;
  import java.awt.event.*;
  import java.awt.*;
  import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
  import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
  import java.beans.Statement;
  import java.sql.*;
  class Log extends imp implements ActionListener {

    JButton login = new JButton("Login");
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    JTextField tx = new JTextField(15);
    JPasswordField pass = new JPasswordField(15);

    Log() {
        //super("Login Autentification");
        setSize(300, 200);
        setLocation(500, 280);
        panel.setLayout(null);


        tx.setBounds(70, 30, 150, 20);
        pass.setBounds(70, 65, 150, 20);
        login.setBounds(110, 100, 80, 20);

        panel.add(login);
        panel.add(tx);
        panel.add(pass);

        getContentPane().add(panel);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);
        actionlogin();
    }

    public void actionlogin() {
        login.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                String puname = tx.getText();
                String ppaswd = pass.getText();
                if (puname.equals("test") && ppaswd.equals("12345")) {
                    newframe regFace = new newframe(); // next GUI....

                    regFace.setVisible(true);
                    dispose();
                } else {

                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Wrong Password / Username");
                    tx.setText("");
                    pass.setText("");
                    tx.requestFocus();
                }




            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }


  }

  class newframe extends imp {


    JButton menu = new JButton("Customer");
    JButton menu2 = new JButton("Reports");
    JButton menu3 = new JButton("Settings");
    JButton menu4 = new JButton("Rooms");
    JPanel p2 = new JPanel();

    //int p = Integer.parseInt(jButton.getText());
    newframe() {
        //super("MENU");
        setSize(300, 200);
        //setLocation(500,280);
        p2.setLayout(null);

        menu.setBounds(150, 10, 100, 50);

        p2.add(menu);

        menu2.setBounds(40, 10, 100, 50);
        p2.add(menu2);

        menu3.setBounds(150, 90, 100, 50);
        p2.add(menu3);
        menu4.setBounds(40, 90, 100, 50);
        p2.add(menu4);

        getContentPane().add(p2);
        //setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        //setVisible(true);

        menu.setActionCommand("1");


        menu2.setActionCommand("2");
        menu3.setActionCommand("3");
        menu4.setActionCommand("4");
        System.out.println("Reached");
    }



    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
        System.out.println("Yahadsdasfasfn bhi");
        int a = Integer.parseInt(ae.getActionCommand());
        switch (a) {
            case 1:
                System.out.println("CUSTOMER");
                Customer C = new Customer();
                C.setSize(400, 400);
                C.setVisible(true);
                C.isvissible(true);
                break;

        }

    }

  }




  class Customer extends imp implements ActionListener {

    JLabel jaddcustomer, jsearchcustomer, jdeletecustomer, jupdatecustomer;
    JButton jb6, jb7, jb8, jb9;

    Customer() {
        //super("Customer");

        Container c = getContentPane();
        FlowLayout fl = new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT);
        c.setLayout(fl);
        jb6 = new JButton("Adding New Customer");
        jaddcustomer = new JLabel("");
        jb6.addActionListener(this);
        jb7 = new JButton("Search Customer Record");
        jsearchcustomer = new JLabel("");
        jb7.addActionListener(this);

        jb8 = new JButton("Delete Customer Record");
        jdeletecustomer = new JLabel("");
        jb8.addActionListener(this);
        jb9 = new JButton("Update Customer Record");
        jupdatecustomer = new JLabel("");
        jb9.addActionListener(this);

        c.add(jb6);
        c.add(jaddcustomer);

        c.add(jb7);
        c.add(jsearchcustomer);
        c.add(jb8);
        c.add(jdeletecustomer);

        c.add(jb9);
        c.add(jupdatecustomer);

    }@Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }



  }

  class login {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {

            // execute.....


            // login
            Log l = new Log(); //displays login page

            Jbuton b = new Jbuton();
            // newframe f=newframe();
            Customer c = new Customer();
            //l.isvissible(false);
            c.isvissible(true);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Exception");

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e.getMessage());
        }
    }
  }
```

Comment: here 's imp class: import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class imp extends JFrame{
 public imp(){}

 public void isvissible(boolean t){
  setVisible(t);
   }


 
        }

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @MahNoor If you have anything you anything you would like to add to your question, than **add it to your question, don't post it as a comment**, please.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your code in the way you handle pressing a JButton. You need to add ActionListener to listen to a pressing event :

```
// make this class implements ActionListener
public class newframe extends imp implements ActionListener{

   JButton menu = new JButton("Customer");
   // add this as the action listener 
   menu.addActionListener(this);
}
```